# best approaches in designing for wordpress a theme, need some advice

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'll be building a Wordpress theme and would be needing some advice in implementing it. [here](http://i48.tinypic.com/u2es0.jpg)'s the outline of my design. I will using 960.gs for the css layout.

Now my worries is what approach will i be using to the services(1,2,3...)? Will I use widget fort hat? Those boxes should be easy to maintain and update. (I've been a Joomla user so, So if I had code it in joomla I had used module for that approach. Is there a similar approach to Wordpress? that you can easily turn on/off the boxes? )

How can I change the look for each page? Some services will not be render in some pages (example, service 1-4 will not be avialabe for 'about page')

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think this belongs to: DocType ? HowToGeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Free ‘Starkers’ Wordpress theme at  [Here](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/free-starkers-wordpress-theme/)

and following the instructions from Chris Coyer of CSS Tricks at [Here](http://css-tricks.com/designing-for-wordpress-complete-series-downloads/)

This really did help me. The screen cast from Chris is a three part series and you would love it.

Update One:

After you do this. I would advice you to get free themes online and see how things are done in different templates. I will help you improve a great deal.

Update Two:

To prevent some widgets from showing on different pages, you would to remove the function that creates that widget from that particular template. Every widget is like a plugin and a function is used to render it on screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already did that. I just haven't finish yet his screencast. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Colour Blend, yeah I think that would be a nice approach. :)